# Android App Keeps stopping after i install the codepush plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, code-push

I try to install the codepush plugin and after that i can run on ionic serve but when i run with ionic cordova run android, it install the app in my phone but I can’t open it. Does someone has same issue? My app still works if i dont install the codepush plugin.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/issues/591
This is the answer for me seems its conflicting with cordova-support-google-services plugin